# Where are women quoted in the Talmud?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, women

On Eruvin 65A, the daughter of Rav Chisda is quoted, talking to her father.

I am seeking a compilation or list of places in the Talmud that a woman is quoted.

Comment: Does every mention of Rabbah bar bar Chana count?

Comment: Why do you assume this is an uncommon occurrence? Have you ever learned Seder Nashim, or Masechtos Niddah or Avodah Zarah? Women are mentioned all the time.

Comment: @DonielF A mention of Rabbah bar bar Chana is not a mention of a woman speaking.

Comment: @DonielF Pls give me a few examples from those masechetot.

Comment: Avodah Zarah 17b-18b discusses the story of R’ Chanina ben Teradyon’s and his wife’s deaths, his daughter’s punishment of being stuck in a brothel, and his daughter-in-law Beruriah’s convincing her husband R’ Meir to go rescue her. (This is the story of Elaka d’Meir Aneini.) Beruriah is also discussed in Pesachim 62b and Eiruvin 53b-54a (in the latter of which she actually disputes a Rav in Halacha and wins). In Kiddushin 80b, regarding the sensitive issue of נשים דעתן קלות עליהן, an argument broke out between R’ Meir and Beruriah, which ultimately resulted in Beruriah’s death.

Comment: Another Beruriah story: https://halakhah.com/berakoth/berakoth_10.html

Comment: @DonielF  Are there many more places where women speak?

Comment: Yeah. All throughout Avodah Zarah are such stories, especially towards the end of the first Perek. Those were just the ones off the top of my head.

Comment: There is also Abaye quoting his matron.

Comment: @user6591  Where you do find this?

Comment: @Yehuda W שבת קלד has a list. But I think there are more scattered here and there. There is a book called women of the talmud which may interest you.